# How to perform Group by Average opreation using DAX in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a sample dataset as below in power BI.

[image]

I want to first group by DeliveryMonth and sum the column Item and then group by Period and take average of column Item. If I directly use average in aggregation it is getting average of whole column. instead I just want average of filtered grouped data by category. my desired output should be as shown below.

[image]

Current Average aggregation shows this in power bi.
[image]

I have tried creating DAX measure using different formulas but did not quite get it. Is there anyway I can get this working? I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated your model, the following calculation should work.
In essence, is grouping the values using `SUMMARIZE` under the desired granularity.
I couldn't match the number `4391.7`, I don't know if that's an error.

### Calculation: Measure

```
Avg. Item Sum = 
    AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[Category],'Table'[DeliveryMonth],'Table'[Period]),
        CALCULATE(sum('Table'[Item]))
        )
```

### Output

| Category | Period | Avg. Item Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Sum20 | 1497.23 |
| B | Sum20 | 525.1 |
| A | Fal20 | 1473.1 |
| B | Fal20 | 440.9 |
| A | Win20 | 1102.2 |
| B | Win20 | 1116.3 |
| A | Spr21 | 780.3 |
| B | Spr21 | 567.1 |

For future reference, the original table as markdown

| Category | DeliveryMonth | Item | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 06 January 2020 | 963.9 | Sum20 |
| A | 06 January 2020 | 500 | Sum20 |
| A | 06 January 2020 | 100 | Sum20 |
| A | 07 January 2020 | 963.9 | Sum20 |
| A | 07 January 2020 | 400 | Sum20 |
| A | 07 January 2020 | 200 | Sum20 |
| A | 08 January 2020 | 963.9 | Sum20 |
| A | 08 January 2020 | 100 | Sum20 |
| A | 08 January 2020 | 300 | Sum20 |
| A | 09 January 2020 | 1473.1 | Fal20 |
| A | 10 January 2020 | 1473.1 | Fal20 |
| A | 11 January 2020 | 1473.1 | Fal20 |
| A | 12 January 2020 | 1102.2 | Win20 |
| A | 01 January 2021 | 1102.2 | Win20 |
| A | 02 January 2021 | 1102.2 | Win20 |
| A | 03 January 2021 | 780.3 | Spr21 |
| A | 04 January 2021 | 780.3 | Spr21 |
| A | 05 January 2021 | 780.3 | Spr21 |
| B | 06 January 2020 | 525.1 | Sum20 |
| B | 07 January 2020 | 525.1 | Sum20 |
| B | 08 January 2020 | 525.1 | Sum20 |
| B | 09 January 2020 | 440.9 | Fal20 |
| B | 10 January 2020 | 440.9 | Fal20 |
| B | 11 January 2020 | 440.9 | Fal20 |
| B | 12 January 2020 | 1116.3 | Win20 |
| B | 01 January 2021 | 1116.3 | Win20 |
| B | 02 January 2021 | 1116.3 | Win20 |
| B | 03 January 2021 | 567.1 | Spr21 |